# What is the patch Level of Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: patch

I need to confirm the patch level of 12.04.4 as being Level 4.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: when i do a cat /etc/issue i get 12.04.4 LTS does this mean the patch level is at 4 because of the .4 ?

Comment: no, that means it is 12.04.04, I have no idea what a "patch level" is you are asking about

Comment: i am requried to be at patch level 4 on ubuntu 12.04 for an application to be supported but from what i can tell there is no way to determine the patch level past the .4

Comment: Can you cite or provide a link to those prerequisites? Maybe you're misinterpreting something.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition (64-bit), patch level 4 or later. The saucy 
or later kernel is also required

Comment: When i do a /etc/lsb-release -a here is my results DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"

Comment: So i took a clone of the virtual server in discussion and performed the apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, upon completion of the updates my /etc/lsb-release shows the version as 12.04.5 LTS this would indicate to me that the .x is a patch level more than a subversion.

Comment: so what is a patch level? who is asking for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the current revision number or patch level in `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/issue`. As far as I can tell, that's what the application prerequisites refer to, because that's the only sub-release versioning scheme of Ubuntu.